# Recommendation for basic ember.js example using latest version?

Tags: ember.js

Could anyone recommend an ember.js example that uses the latest version of the library? There are many good tutorials but they all seem to use old versions of ember and all of them break for one reason or another when pointed at the newest one; even the basic snippets on the ember.js home page don't work out of the box though I suspect this is because they require ember-data and I haven't even begun to look into that yet. Just trying to get started with the framework, looking for a way to get off the ground!

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

I know that feeling! Starting with Ember could really be easier.

For the start I would recommend reading [Advice on & Instruction in the Use Of Ember.js](http://trek.github.com/) by Trek Glowacki. The example application is also available as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ZKXyg/). It looks messy, but it is a working Ember application using the Router.

If you need a basic Ember skeleton to start out, I will point to my own [Ember CoffeeScript Start Kit](https://github.com/stravid/emberjs-coffeescript-start-kit/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts). It includes the most minimal Ember application you need to get started. A `Router`, an `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` plus template. Go take a look :-)

Comment: Thanks - this looks like exactly what I needed. We should link to it in many places so it percolates higher on Google and saves others the aggravation of working with other tutorials that also seem like exactly what they need, but that by virtue of their reliance on older versions of ember rely on outdated paradigms and don't work with the current code! Also poking around with the CoffeeScript starter kit, seems like a reasonable way to get started once I understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds familiar.

I've been using [ember rest example](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_rest_example) for a combination of Ember and rails, if that is of interest for your goals.

Comment: thanks. this is helpful, I'll take a closer look - although I'd also like something short and straightforward that doesn't integrate tightly with rails, as ruby and rails is not a part of my project